# Как узнать, есть ли в строке большие буквы?

Tags: char, java, строки

Как это можно реализовать? Единственная идея, которая сейчас есть, - разбить строку на символы и далее каждый символ проверять на буква ли это, если да, то потом проверять не большая ли.

Мне кажется, что это будет как-то не совсем корректно и должны быть более красивые решения, что ли.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регулярные выражения вас спасут. Если вы хотите по букве проверять, нужно использовать к строке с буквой метод `str.matches("A-Z")`, что даст логическое true, если символ есть большая буква.

Немного пошаманив с регулярным выражением, можно написать и для проверки целой строки, но тут надо учитывать все возможные варианты. Проще - побуквенно.

Есть ещё вариант - создать вторую строку через:

```
String str2 = str1.toLowerCase();
```

и потом сравнить строки. Если будет несовпадение - где-то есть большие буквы, но этот вариант подходит, только если нужен сам факт наличия больших букв.

Есть оракловая [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) по регулярным выражениям, правда, на английском.

Comment: Для проверки целой строки достаточно регулярное выражение заключить в квадратные скобки, то есть проверять по выражению `[A-Z]` и в match'е будет первая буква, отвечающая условию.

Answer (score 6):

Есть такой статический метод `Character.isUpperCase(char);` он сам проверяет буква ли это, и неважно какого алфавита. Как-то так

```
String str="teststrinG123OPIvaaaav";
        boolean result=false;
        char[] array=str.toCharArray();
        for(char x:array){
            if(Character.isUpperCase(x)){
                result=true;
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: а разве он не выводит тру только тогда, когда все буквы в верхнем регистре?

Comment: добавил кусок кода

Comment: @EugMirk совершенно очевидно, что нет, т.к. `isUpperCase` - это метод класса `Character`, каждый экземпляр которого представляет лишь один конкретный символ. Вы основные моменты сначала поймите, а потом уже на форумы с вопросами идите.

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант с новыми Stream в JDK 8

```
public class UpperCaseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String someupper = "this string Contains Some Uppercase Chars";
        String alllower = "this string contains no uppercase chars";
        System.out.println(containsUppercase(someupper));
        System.out.println(containsUppercase(alllower));
    }

    private static boolean containsUppercase(String str) {
        return str.codePoints().filter(Character::isUpperCase)
            .findFirst().isPresent();
    }
}
```

Comment: О, в Джаве появилось LINQ! :)

Лучше наверное просто [`anyMatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Answer (score 2):

Эх вы... Все же просто, надо всю строку перевести в `lowerCase` и сравнить с исходной строкой. Если строки идентичны, значит все символы были маленькие, иначе хотя бы одна была большая:

```
boolean isAnyUpperCase(String s) {
   if(s.equals(s.toLowerCase()))
     return false;
   return true;
}
```

**P.S.** Regexp'ы и проч. LinQ - в данном контексте это зло

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, а может все-таки

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
      if(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))
        return true;
    return false;

лучше?

Comment: @avp: Ваш способ должен быть по идее быстрее.

Comment: Ну я смотрел не в сторону быстроты, а в сторону альтернативности кода

Comment: @Barmaley: Я не критиковал вашу идею, что вы! Если искать действительно самый быстрый путь, можно дойти до [извращений](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8894258/276994).

Answer (score 1):

Guava:

```
CharMatcher.JAVA_UPPER_CASE.matchesAnyOf("abC"); // true
CharMatcher.JAVA_UPPER_CASE.matchesAnyOf("abc"); // false
```

Answer (score -2):

На самом деле у каждого символа только 1 бит отвечает за регистр, можно только его и проверять(Если нужен только английский алфавит например)... Это и будет самый быстрый путь

Comment: @Isaev: Ыыы? А вы знаете о существовании неанглийских языков?

Comment: @Isaev примерчик можно?

Comment: @argamidon, a..z имеют коды $41-$5A, A..Z соответственно $61-$7A, т.е. если 6 бит включен, то символ lowerCase иначе upperCase

@VladD, в задании никаких данных о других языках не давалось, потому по-умолчанию писал о английском... А вы уверены, если уж на то пошло, что ваш containsUppercase будет корректно работать с китайскими иероглифами?

Comment: @Isaev: `Character::isUpperCase` должен работать правильно со всеми символами Unicode, разумеется. С китайскими иероглифами проблем нет, т. к. в китайском нет самого понятия прописных и строчных символов.

Гипотетическая проверка одного бита посчитает пробел строчной, а `@` заглавной буквой. Так что проблемы у вашего подхода есть даже в области US-ASCII, не говоря уже об используемых в английском литературном языке французских (café, naïveté) и немецких словах (Übermensch).

Если автор не пишет о конкретном языке, проверка должна работать _независимо_ от языка.

Comment: @VladD, всегда есть возможность оптимизации, в каждом конкретном случае... Лишь это я хотел донести до вас. Когда у меня стояла подобная задаче, мне вполне хватило данной проверки, чтобы всё прекрасно и быстро работало и даже без привязки к какому-либо конкретному ЯП